# How to write a matches excluding a series of space character (' ') from the input?

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, validation

I am having a problem with my grails project right now, I wanted to write a matches, that would best fit the allowable characters for my input fields. I have written a matches, that throws an error message if the input characters contain a single space character., but no longer works if the input contains a series of spaces. This is my code:

```
newPassword nullable: false, minSize: 8, matches: /[0-9a-zA-Z_\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)~!@#%&-=]*/, blank: false, notEqualToAnyProperty:['username', 'emailAddress'],validator: { value, obj ->
           (obj.currentPassword != value && value != '')
        }
```

These are the sample inputs:

1) 'rain drops' - my matches works, it returns an error message that the input contains an invalid character.

2) '          ' - series of spaces; my program returns an error message that should be displayed for the blank constraint instead of displaying the error message for my matches constraint which is the, "input contains an invalid character", since the input doesn't match the allowable input characters.

Any help from you guys? Thanks!

Comment: Are you really stopping people using spaces in their passwords? By doing so, you're making your app less secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add any begin (^) or end ($) tags to your regular expression, as the `matches` constraint attempts to match the entire String input against the Pattern, thus your first test correctly fails against the constraint.

For your second test where the input is only a series of spaces `'    '`, your `matches` constraint will never run.  Both `blank` and `nullable` are constraints which can block the running of other constraints if they fail.  The `matches` constraint will not run in your case because the `blank` constraint returns a failure on an all-whitespace input.

Comment: yes you are right shmolly159! that's why I tried another way to resolve the issue..Hope it will work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try matches: /[0-9a-zA-Z_[]\\^\$.\|\?*+()~!@#%&-=]**+$**/

I just added a dollar at the end and changed the star to a plus. Dollar means end of line. Maybe the match is returning true because the first part of the string does indeed match.

The reason I changed the star to a plus is because * matches zero or more. That's the case in your empty string. The + requires one or more.

You can require a min sequence of 8 such chars in the regexp but that might make you lose your minsize validation error message.

Comment: I've tried your codes..but, it still behaves the same, if I input a series of spaces like 10 character spaces or even a single space without any alphanumeric characters, it throws an error message that my input should not be blank, instead of displaying the error message which pertains to invalid character.

Comment: And what if they have valid chars mixed in with spaces? It seems to me  empty value and 10 spaces should say "cant be blank" as you are getting right now. That's more helpful in that case than "you've entered an invalid char".